# http.get - how to properly catch a 404

Tags: angular, http, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I am building a calendar app that gets data for each day from a (currently mocked) backend.
On correct urls for the http.get, this works just fine, though if the url is wrong, or there is no data/json object in the backend for the requested day (for example, weekends don't have any data), I (obviously) get a 404, though the log in the console rarely shows it, instead it always gives me the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Obviously it can't have an expected character there as no Json object exists for the requested day. Checking the Network analysis shows me that it is indeed a 404 error though.

I use the basic http.get and handleError from here https://angular.io/guide/http#subscribe

Code of the service with the http.get:

```
getDayInfo(date: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.gttp.get('somepath/' + date + '/somemoreinfo')
    .map(this.extractData, // works just fine
         console.log('map running for date: ', date)
    ) 
    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
  if (res != null) {
    let body = res.json();;
    return body;
  } else { // else return an empty dummy json, doesn't really work here
    return '[{"id": "", "userId": "", "userName": "", "type": { "name": "" }, "date": {' +
    '"startDate": "", "endDate": "", "startTime": "", "endTime": "" }   }]'; }
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
  console.log('Errorhandling triggered'); 
  let errMsg: string;
  if (error instanceof Response) {
    console.log('Errorhandling if-block'); // this triggers on a 404
    const body = error.json() || '';
    const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
    errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || '' } ${err}`;
  } else {
    errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
  }
  console.error('Error ', errMsg); // this never appears in the log though
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

The goal for me is to catch a 404 instead of having it throw the JSON.parse error I posted earlier and handle it by sending an empty json object (or a dummy json object) instead so the day in the calendar simply displays nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is on the line

```
const body = error.json() || '';
```

The problem is that when your back-end sends an error (here being a 404), you don't send a JSON object. So if you use `error.json()`, don't expect to get a JSON object !

Either you return a JSON error from your back-end, or you don't use the `json()` function in your error handler.

When you don't use the `json()` function, you also gain access to the `status` property (if I recall correctly it's this one) which contains the error code. So you can put conditions on it, like if it's 404, you do what you want.

I hop I made myslef clear, if not, feel free to ask for more details !

Comment: I had taken that part of my handleError function directly from Angular.io, thought it'd be fine as it is... will experiment in that area a little.

Comment: Yeah I did that too when I started, but you have to take into consideration that the Response highly depends on your back-end, and (for my part at least) you rarely think about sending a json object in case of an error.

Comment: seems testing for error.status as a string works, so I seem to be able to catch it here and handle it further in my component. At this point, I believe this will be the solution I need, so thanks from my end

Comment: Try a `console.log(error)` and see which fields you can use too. And don't worry, it's neither a fix nor a workaround, Response objects were meant to be used like this, you will see they even have a `_body`, which in fact is what is returned (as JSON) by the `json()` function